# how to restart solr server (cloudera) from command line

Tags: solr, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I want to restart solr cloud from command line or shell script. when i use the command sudo service solr-server restart it gives unrecognized service.

is there a way to restart solr cloud from command line?

I am using cloudea-serach 4.3 cdh 4.7

and also

1)is there a way to know the backend command executed by cloudera manager when the restart action is fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is having the same question:

You can use the `curl POST` command

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://ipaddress:7180/api/v4/clusters/<Cluster_name>/services/solr1/commands/start -H 'Content-type:aplication/json; charset=utf-8';
```

Comment: I'm getting this error while running the query: {
  "message" : "No content to map due to end-of-input\n at [Source: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@63620408; line: 1, column: 1]"
}.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with @Bhuvan's solution just added escape char to run from Bash.

```
curl -k  -X POST -u user:password 'https://ipaddr:7183/api/v19/clusters/clustername/commands/restart' -H "Content-Type: **application\\/json**"
```